# Transactions for file operations in Laravel

Tags: laravel, transactions, laravel-6

In Laravel I can do database transactions by passing a closure to the `DB::transaction` function.

Does Laravel have any support for a similar feature for the `File` or `Storage` facade? Where the file operations are run in a transaction, with rollback in case a file operation fails?

I'm imagining something like

```
$files = ... // Something that returns a collection

File::transaction(function () use ($files) {
  $files->each(function() {
    File::move(....);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no built in way of doing it so you'd have to make an implementation yourself.

A simple method of achieving it would be

```
$fileName = "";   // or $fileNames ( array ) if multiple file uploads
$files = "" // to be used if you're going to update or delete files. Again if multiple file modifications then use array
try{
    /* Just a note, but your new file could overwrite any existing files,
        so before uploading, check if another file exists with same filename
        And if it does, load that file and keep it in the $files variable
    */
    // Upload File
    $fileName = // name of uploaded file
    $files = // Any existing file you're going to modify. Load the entire file data, not just the name
    // Modify/Delete a file
}( \Exception $e ){
    // Now delete the file using fileName or $fileNames if the variable is not empty
    // If you modified/deleted any file, then undo those modifications using the data in $files ( if it's not empty )
}
```

In this method, existing files are loaded to memory, but if there are multiple large files, it might be better to move them to a temporary location instead, and move them back if any exception is thrown. Just don't forget to delete these temporary files if the file transaction is a success